# Python - Bash - random numbers

Tags: python, bash, random

Given a script 'random.sh' with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

RANDOM=`python -v -d -S -c "import random; print random.randrange(500, 800)"`
echo $RANDOM
```

Running this produces random numbers **outside** the given range:

```
[root@localhost nms]# ./random.sh
23031
[root@localhost nms]# ./random.sh
9276
[root@localhost nms]# ./random.sh
10996
```

renaming the RANDOM variable to RAND, gives me random numbers from the given range, i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

RAND=`python -v -d -S -c "import random; print random.randrange(500, 800)"`
echo $RAND
```

gives:

```
[root@localhost nms]# ./random.sh
671
[root@localhost nms]# ./random.sh
683
[root@localhost nms]# ./random.sh
537
```

My question is -- why? :)

Comment: note: I added the -v -d flags to debug this further, without any luck. The result without them is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RANDOM is a predefined bash variable. From the manpage:

```
RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between
       0 and 32767 is generated.  The sequence of random numbers may be
       initialized by assigning a value to RANDOM.  If RANDOM is unset,
       it loses its special properties,  even  if  it  is  subsequently
       reset.
```

So if you really want to use the RANDOM variable name, do this:

```sh
unset RANDOM
RANDOM=`..your script..`
```

Comment: and ... of course. I was so fixated on debugging the python side that I forgot about the bash side. Thanks John.

Answer (score 2):

[`$RANDOM`](http://islandlinux.org/howto/generate-random-numbers-bash-scripting) is an internal `bash` function that returns a pseudorandom integer in the range 0-32767.

Thus in the first example you're seeing random numbers generated by `bash` and not by your Python script. When you assign to `RANDOM`, you're simply seeding `bash`'s random number generator.

Answer (score 1):

$RANDOM is a predefined variable in bash.

Open a new terminal and try it :

```
> echo $RANDOM
6007
> echo $RANDOM
122211
```